# Worker stuck in a Sandbox?

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash, air

Trying to figure out why I can login with my rest API just fine on the main thread but not in a worker. All communication channels are operating fine and I am able to load it up no problem. However, when it tries to send some data it just hangs.

```
    [Embed(source="../bin/BGThread.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]      
    private static var BackgroundWorker_ByteClass:Class;
    public static function get BackgroundWorker():ByteArray
    {
        return new BackgroundWorker_ByteClass();
    }
```

On a test script:

```
    public function Main() 
    {
        fBCore.init("secrets", "my-firebase-id");
        trace("Init");
        //fBCore.auth.addEventListener(FBAuthEvent.LOGIN_SUCCES, hanldeFBSuccess);
        fBCore.auth.addEventListener(AuthEvent.LOGIN_SUCCES, hanldeFBSuccess);
        fBCore.auth.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleIOError);

        fBCore.auth.email_login("admin@admin.admin", "password");

    }

    private function handleIOError(e:IOErrorEvent):void 
    {
        trace("IO error");
        trace(e.text); //Nothing here
    }

    private function hanldeFBSuccess(e:AuthEvent):void 
    {
        trace("Main login success.");
        trace(e.message);//Complete success.
    }
```

When triggered by a class via an internal worker channel passed from Main on init:

Primordial:

```
    private function handleLoginClick(e:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        login_mc.buttonMode = false;
        login_mc.play();
        login_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, handleLoginClick);

        log("Logging in as " + email_mc.text_txt.text);
        commandChannel.send([BGThreadCommand.LOGIN, email_mc.text_txt.text, password_mc.text_txt.text]);
    }
```

Worker:

```
                    ...
                    case BGThreadCommand.LOGIN:
                        log("Logging in with " + message[1] + "::" + message[2]); //Log goes to a progress channel and comes to the main thread reading the outputs successfully.
                        fbCore.auth.email_login(message[1], message[2]);
                        fbCore.auth.addEventListener(AuthEvent.LOGIN_SUCCES, loginSuccess); //Nothing
                        fbCore.auth.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, handleLoginIOError); //Fires
                        break;
```

Auth Rest Class: https://github.com/sfxworks/FirebaseREST/blob/master/src/net/sfxworks/firebaseREST/Auth.as

Is this a worker limitation or a security sandbox issue? I have a deep feeling it is the latter of the two. If that's the case how would I load the worker in a way that also gives it the proper permissions to act?

Comment: Oh, a **good** question at once. Cannot tell for sure, but let me quote the official manual: *Several runtime APIs are not available in code running in a background worker. These primarily consist of APIs related to user input and output mechanisms, or operating system elements like windows and dragging.* **Note**: *Native Extensions are not supported for background and secondary workers.*

Comment: @Organis I did see this when doing my research. The only thing I am using in this thread is a URLLoader and a URLStream as that is what my rest api is built on. The api is not an ANE so this that is why I am wondering why it wouldn't be working. Though since both of those are async anyway I was wondering if AIR prevented a worker from doing this.

Comment: Well. What kind of sandbox the worker is in? Does it match the main app sandbox? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Security.html#sandboxType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely ignored the giveAppPrivelages property in the [createWorker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/WorkerDomain.html#createWorker()) function. Sorry Stackoverflow. Sometimes I make bad questions when I get little (or none in this case) sleep the night before.